# In Julia, how to do method dispatch properly on arguments of (super-)types that are also supplied by the caller?

Tags: julia

I would like to define a function `f(x, t::Type)` that executes different behavior depending on whether `isa(x, t)`. Let's say that I want to call `b1(x)` if it is, and `b2(x)` otherwise.

I know that I can do a dynamic check at runtime like this:

```
function f(x, t::Type)
  if isa(x, t)
    b1(x)
  else
    b2(x)
  end
end
```

However, is there a way to do this purely with parametric method dispatch? For example, if I define

```
f{T}(x::T, t::Type{T}) = b1(x)
f(x, t::Type) = b2(x)
```

for `f(1, Int)` and `f(1.0, Int)` the correct behavior is called. But I want this to also work for all subtypes of `t`:

```
f(1, Number)
```

<s>This actually calls `b2` because the first signature of `f` does not match. Interestingly, though, `f(x::Number, t::Type{Number}) = b1(x)` would match in this case.</s>

Am I missing something obvious here?

*This was appearently a bug and is fixed in 0.4.*

---

*Questions:*

1. <s>Why does `f{T}(x::T, t::Type{T})` not match for `f(1, Number)`, even though there is a type substitution for `T` (`Number`) that would match?</s>
2. Using `f{T2, T1 <: T2}(x::T1, t::Type{T2})` or something similar does not work because appearently all static parameters come in scope only after the complete static parameter list is closed. Why?
3. Are there any performance penalties for using the dynamic approach instead?
4. What about defining the methods as an inner function, so I can bind `t` to a local variable, like this:
   `function f(x, t::Type); g(x::t) = b1(x); g(x) = b2(x); g(x) end`

   That works, but what are the performance costs?
5. What's the idiomatic/preferred way to solve this?

*(I had tried this on 0.3.2.)*

Comment: I have version Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+1307 and f(1, Number) calls b1

Comment: You are right, I have confirmed that this works on 0.4.0-dev+1521. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. AFAICT it should. As user3580870 commented, this appears to work in Julia 0.4.
2. This is "triangular dispatch" and is not (yet) implemented. See [#3766](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3766).
3. Depends. The compiler can evaluate `isa(x, t)` at compile time and eliminate the branch. However, there are still a few possible ways using `isa` could be suboptimal:

   - If the two branches return different types, type inference will not be able to infer the return type properly because it happens before `isa(x, t)` is made into a constant. (This would likely be costly; the other possible deoptimizations below are probably not a big deal.)
   - If one branch performs heap allocation but the other does not, an unnecessary GC frame may be emitted.
   - The function may not be inlined.
4. <s>An inner function will have the same performance problems as using `isa` and more.</s> As of Julia 0.5, an inner function should be as efficient as a top-level function in this case.
5. File a bug ;-). I think this is supposed to work. It's possible whatever fixed this in 0.4 can be backported to 0.3. But failing that, `isa` is not a bad approach provided that it doesn't cause a type inference issue.

Comment: Thank you for this quick and excellent answer. This indeed works in 0.4, which solves my problem.

Comment: But could you please elaborate on the performance issues with the inner function approach, or direct me to a place where I can learn more? Why is this so much worse than defining the functions at the top level? And just to clarify: If the functions called indeed return objects of differing types, the `f{T}(x::T, t::Type{T}) = b1(x)`-approach would be faster?